# Initial 3D vector member between constructor list and constructor body

Tags: c++

I declare a 3d vector member in header file for Example Class:

.h file:

```
Class Example{

    Example();

priveate:

    vector<vector<vector<int> > > v;

};
```

I want to initialization v with some vale, and then I try two different way:

Way 1 (init in constructor list):

```
Example::Example()
    :v(2, vector<vector<int> >(2, vector<int>(2, -1)))
{}
```

Way 2 (init in constructor body):

```
Example::Example()   
{
    v(2, vector<vector<int> >(2, vector<int>(2, -1)));
}
```

Way 1 can pass compilation, but, way 2 shows out error during compilation statge.
Error message:

```
no match call to vector<vector<vector<int> > >(int, vector<vector<int>)
```

I can not figure out why way 1 pass, and way 2 fail.
Can someone explain it for me?
And if use way2 to init vector in body, how to revise the code?

Comment: As an expression `v(2, vector<vector<int> >(2, vector<int>(2, -1)))` is a *function call*. If `v` is an object and not a function it's the same as `v.operator()(2, vector<vector<int> >(2, vector<int>(2, -1)))`. You can't *initialize* an object once you're in the constructor function body, just like you can't initialize such an object in any other function (would you expect it to work in e.g. `main`?). Use the initializer list to initialize the objects. Do *assignment* inside the function body.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```cpp
v(2, vector<vector<int> >(2, vector<int>(2, -1)));
```

in your Way 2 is trying to use `operator()` with 2 arguments with `v`.

However, such operator is not defined.

Instead of this, you can *assign* a new vector to `v` like this:

```cpp
v = vector<vector<vector<int> > >(2, vector<vector<int> >(2, vector<int>(2, -1)));
```